# repaint method for moving an object randomly

Tags: java, swing, repaint, jcomponent

I am trying to move an object randomly. I have my GUI class which uses another class (lets say Obj) to create a new image and then start the thread to make the object move randomly. But my repaint() does not work in this context. The code below can give you an idea about how I am using the repaint method.
thanks,

Gui class

```
 public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

     public void addNewObj(){
                Obj f = new Obj();
                x = panel.getGraphics();
                f.paint(x);
                Thread thr=new Thread(f);
                thr.start();
            }
    }
```

Create object class

```
public class Obj extends JPanel implements Runnable
{

public Obj()
{


    try {
    myImage = ImageIO.read(new File("b:\\imgs\\bottle.jpg"));
    }
      catch (IOException e) {}
}

public void run()
{
    long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;
    beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (true)
    {

        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
        sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;


        try
        {
             moveRandom();
             repaint();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is very basic: Never paint an object in the way you do. You should add it to the frame or an container. This is also the reason, why repaint() doesn't work. Your object never makes it into the componenthierachy, and therefore repaint will only repaint this single object, but nothing else (including the frame, which should be repainted). Simply add the object directly to the frame, validate and repaint the frame.

the new addNewObj:

```
public void addNewObj(){
      Obj f = new Obj();

      Thread t = new Thread(f);
      t.start();

      panel.add(f);//add it to the panel
      panel.validate();//validate the hierachy
      panel.repaint();//repaint the whole thing to make the new obj visible
}
```

And override your Obj class to paint the objects:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.drawImage(myImage , 0 , 0 , Color.white , null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. could you please give me an example with a piece of code.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. I understand what you but I am newbie. I already have my paint method (see below) to display my image. If I use your code then i don't get any image but small empty squares that does not move. 'code' public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(frogImage, x, y, this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}'code'

Comment: sry, i forgot to use your paintmethod to paint an image to the screen. this edit should help ^^

Comment: you shouldn't use paint(Graphics g), but paintComponent(Graphics g). Thats the correct way to paint a component according to the javadoc., appart from that you could simply move your code from paint to paintComponent and everything should work fine.

Comment: sorry but it's still does not work. I still get those small empty squares and no images

Comment: is the layoutmanager of the frame set to null? this might be a reason. if it isn't try setting the layoutmanager to null and manually applying a size to the objects

Comment: this is my setting:    `public static void main (String[] args) {
      TheHungryCyberPet frame = new TheHungryCyberPet();
         frame.setSize(700, 500);
         frame.setResizable(false); //disable resizing
         frame.createGUI();
         frame.show();
     }`
     

                                     `private void createGUI() {
         setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         Container window = getContentPane();
         window.setLayout(new FlowLayout() );`

Comment: ok, thanks. you set the layout to a new flowlayout, this won't let you move the images around freely and they are smaller than your images (i think). you have two options: either set the layoutmanager to null, set the size of the components manually and move the components around, or implement a table with all the images and their positions and do everything using that table and one component that paints all images.